# Why is my PC’s IP address not shown by nmap?

Tags: networking, nmap

I scanned my home network using `nmap 192.168.178.*` and `192.168.178.0-255` but it doesn't show the IP of my PC. Then when I scan only my PC using `-Pn` it finds it. So why is my PC hidden?

And even after finding it with `-Pn` why it doesn't show real info about my OS, it shows only like Windows, Windows 98, while it is Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe by default `nmap` does a ping scan of the target IP addresses. If your host doesn't respond to pings — perhaps because it is running a local software firewall that blocks it in order to be less findable on the network — then `nmap` will not be able to find it with pings.

When OS fingerprinting fails, it is usually because `nmap` could not get the target host to respond to much of anything, so `nmap` was unable to learn anything meaningful.

If you have a firewall enabled on that target host, then it seems like it is doing its job.

Comment: ok, thnx, good to know, I just use a normal windows firewall, doe it mean too that there are more powerful tools than nmap ?

Answer (score 0):

Because all automatic tools don't have the precision to obtain a 100% in any scanning phase. (Nmap in recon. or ZAP in vuln.)

And the reason why nmap don't shows your Windonws PC is because all Windows system have firewalls rules against ICMP protocol, (ping). Better try `-Pn`, `-PU` (UDP), or another ICMP ping types like `-PE`, `-PP` or `-PM`.
Sources:

1. [Host Discovery Techniques](https://nmap.org/book/host-discovery-techniques.html)
2. [TryHackMe Nmap module](https://tryhackme.com/module/nmap)